# How to create a customer in Stripe when i create a Contact (or any object ) in salesforce with help of flow

Tags: visual-workflow, integration, stripe

I have installed Stripe for Salesforce Platform App from app exchange to my salesforce org.
Now i want to create the functionality like when I create any contact than it should automatically create a customer in Stripe with same Name and Email (with the help of Flow).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a Stripe Customer from Salesforce here is some enablement material. https://github.com/stripe/salesforce-connector-examples/tree/main/customer-metadata-example

This includes adding and setting Metadata but guessing that would be needed in this integration anyway.